# How context works in Android?

Tags: android, android-context

I want to know what is the context an interface or an abstract class. I have read the documentation. I have come to a conclusion that context is an abstract class, but we can not make the object of abstract class according to java programming. Therefore can any body help me
to understand what they are and how they work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

public abstract class Context extends Object

is written on the top of the page :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Here, you can see how Activity class extends context.

Comment: can you tell me about direct or indirect sub classes